# PySpark regex engine not matching

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on a regex to apply to a PySpark DataFrame column.

I can't happen to reproduce in PySpark the result of my working regex [running here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dpIKoy/1).

I've tried several methods (see below) and none seem to be working (even tested on specific Java regex's engine). I wish to fetch the group showed on the example above.

```
(\w+(?:\s*|\d*)\s+RUE\s.*)
[\s\-]+(\d*\s*RUE\s+.*)
```

Code sample:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('RESIDENCE LA VENDEENNE 80 81 RUE LOUIS LUMIERE',)
], ["adresse1"])

df.withColumn("adresse1", regexp_replace("adresse1", "(\w+(?:\s*|\d*)\s+RUE\s.*)", '$1')).show(truncate=False)
```

The output I get is my **unchanged** column:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|adresse1                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|RESIDENCE LA VENDEENNE 80  81 RUE LOUIS LUMIERE|
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

When I'm expecting the column to be valued at

```
81 RUE LOUIS LUMIERE
```

So far I have absolutely no guess, especially as my previous ones worked (matched) as predicted.

---

Spark config:

- Version 2.4.0-cdh6.2.0
- Scala version 2.11.12
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_222

Comment: Side note, you can simplify your pattern to `\w+\d*\s+RUE\s.*`

Comment: Indeed I replaced it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be using [`regexp_extract`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) instead of [`regexp_replace`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract

df.withColumn(
    "adresse1", 
    regexp_extract("adresse1", r"(\w+(?:\s*|\d*)\s+RUE\s.*)", 1)
).show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------+
#|adresse1            |
#+--------------------+
#|81 RUE LOUIS LUMIERE|
#+--------------------+
```

---

To keep the column value unchanged if the pattern doesn't match, you can use [`pyspark.sql.Column.rlike`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike) and [`when`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

pat = r"(\w+(?:\s*|\d*)\s+RUE\s.*)"

df.withColumn(
    "adresse1", 
    when(
        col("adresse1").rlike(pat), regexp_extract("adresse1", pat, 1)
    ).otherwise(col("adresse1"))
).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Alright it totally works, thanks for pointing this out. Went too fast on the API documentation, and mistook the two of them.

Comment: A question occurs in my mind as I keep advancing on this subject @pault, how can I prevent the row value to be overwritten by an empty value if the regex didnt match? Do I have to use a 3rd column to store the regex extract and then replace the content of my original column only if the regex's output is not empty ?

Comment: Yes something like that. Another option would be to use `rlike` to test if the column matches the pattern first- I've posted an update.

Comment: This feels way more straightforward and readable (to me at least). Thanks again for this lightning fast answer. Im currently testing it.

Comment: Does it have a big impact on the physical schema ? Mine doesnt look like anything to me, but it surely seems like it's taking a significant amount of time. Despite still using native PySpark functions.

Comment: It should not your slowdown is probably elsewhere, but it's impossible to tell without knowing more about your other code.